# Remove non-numeric rows in one column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

There is a dataframe like the following, and it has one unclean column 'id' which it sholud be numeric column

```
id, name
1,  A
2,  B
3,  C
tt, D
4,  E
5,  F
de, G
```

Is there a concise way to remove the rows because tt and de are not numeric values

```
tt,D
de,G
```

to make the dataframe clean?

```
id, name
1,  A
2,  B
3,  C
4,  E
5,  F
```

Comment: Your **example column has str type everywhere**, not mixed-type like (say) `pd.Series([1, 2.2, True, 'ignore'])`. Some solutions here rely on assuming str type or methods. To not break on more general mixed-type column, you'll need`s[s.str.isnumeric() == True]` since `s.str.isnumeric() ` returns `Nan` for int and float.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could use standard  method of strings [`isnumeric`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) and apply it to each value in your `id` column:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
id,name
1,A
2,B
3,C
tt,D
4,E
5,F
de,G
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))

In [55]: df
Out[55]: 
   id name
0   1    A
1   2    B
2   3    C
3  tt    D
4   4    E
5   5    F
6  de    G

In [56]: df[df.id.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]
Out[56]: 
  id name
0  1    A
1  2    B
2  3    C
4  4    E
5  5    F
```

Or if you want to use `id` as index you could do:

```
In [61]: df[df.id.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())].set_index('id')
Out[61]: 
   name
id     
1     A
2     B
3     C
4     E
5     F
```

#### Edit. Add timings

Although case with `pd.to_numeric` is not using `apply` method it is almost two times slower than with applying `np.isnumeric` for `str` columns. Also I add option with using pandas [`str.isnumeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) which is less typing and still faster then using `pd.to_numeric`. But `pd.to_numeric` is more general because it could work with any data types (not only strings).

```
df_big = pd.concat([df]*10000)

In [3]: df_big = pd.concat([df]*10000)

In [4]: df_big.shape
Out[4]: (70000, 2)

In [5]: %timeit df_big[df_big.id.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]
15.3 ms ± 2.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit df_big[df_big.id.str.isnumeric()]
20.3 ms ± 171 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit df_big[pd.to_numeric(df_big['id'], errors='coerce').notnull()]
29.9 ms ± 682 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: I tested it on python 2, but `pd.to_numeric` is faster than `isdigit()`. `%timeit subx1=sub[sub.BAN.apply(lambda x: str(x).isdigit())]` is 5.67 sec. Compare to 4.46 sec for 
`%timeit subx2=sub[pd.to_numeric(sub.BAN, errors='coerce').notnull()]`. Python 2 `str` does not has `isnumeric()`

Comment: in your first example: do I need "inplace=True?"

Answer (score 132):

Using `pd.to_numeric`

```
In [1079]: df[pd.to_numeric(df['id'], errors='coerce').notnull()]
Out[1079]:
  id  name
0  1     A
1  2     B
2  3     C
4  4     E
5  5     F
```

Explanation:

This will coerce all non-numeric values to `NaN`, which will then be flagged as `False` using `notnull()`. Other numeric values will be converted to `True`.

This filtering mask is then passed to the dataframe to select those rows whose id is numeric only.

If you want to overwrite the dataframe, don't forget to reassign the result.

Comment: If you want to retain the column as a number and not an object, you might need to call `pd.to_numeric` separately.

Comment: No `apply` :D !

Comment: (It's not inplace)

Comment: Is there a way to do this if NaN is a valid value for the column but not a non-numeric like "abc"? This would filter out both nulls and non-numerics

Comment: Is this faster than `.apply`?

Answer (score 14):

Given that `df` is your dataframe,

```
import numpy as np
df[df['id'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, np.int64)))]
```

What it does is passing each value in the `id` column to the `isinstance` function and checks if it's an `int`. Then it returns a boolean array, and finally returning only the rows where there is `True`.

If you also need to account for `float` values, another option is:

```
import numpy as np
df[df['id'].apply(lambda x: type(x) in [int, np.int64, float, np.float64])]
```

Note that either way is not inplace, so you will need to reassign it to your original df, or create a new one:

```
df = df[df['id'].apply(lambda x: type(x) in [int, np.int64, float, np.float64])]
# or
new_df = df[df['id'].apply(lambda x: type(x) in [int, np.int64, float, np.float64])]
```

Comment: The code in the first block empty completed my dataframe.

Answer (score 5):

`x.isnumeric()` does not test return `True` when `x` is of type `float`.

One way to filter out values which can be converted to `float`:

`df[df['id'].apply(lambda x: is_float(x))]`

```py
def is_float(x):
    try:
        float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: I used this approach since I had two columns I wanted to check if they were numeric, not one.

`df.apply(lambda x: is_float(x.col1) and is_float(x.col2), axis=1)`

I think we need to handle TypeError too?

Answer (score 3):

How about this?
The `.str` accessor is one of my favorites :)

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'id':   {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: 'tt', 4: '4', 5: '5', 6: 'de'},
        'name': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D',  4: 'E', 5: 'F', 6: 'G'}
    }
)

df_clean = df[df.id.str.isnumeric()]
```

*Supplement (2021-06-22)*

If the `id` contains some kind of headache-makers (such as `float`, `None`, `nan`), you can forcefully cast them to the `str` data type using `astype('str')`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'id':   {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: 3.14, 4: '4', 5: '5', 6: None, 7: np.nan},
        'name': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D',  4: 'E', 5: 'F', 6: 'G',  7: 'H'}
    }
)

df_clean = df[df.id.astype('str').str.isnumeric()]
```

Primitive, but it works anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use the [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method:

```
In [5]: df.query('id.str.isnumeric()')
Out[5]: 
  id  name
0  1     A
1  2     B
2  3     C
4  4     E
5  5     F
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamic way to do it, this only works for int64 and float 64, if you have other numeric data types in your dataframe make sure you add them to the if statement

```
# make dataframe of column data types
col_types = df.dtypes.to_frame()
col_types.columns = ['dtype']

#make list of zeros
drop_it = [0]*col_types.shape[0]
k = 0

#make it a one if the data isn't numeric
#if you have other numeric types you need to add them to if statement
for t in col_types.dtype:
    if t != 'int64' and t != 'float64':
        drop_it[k] = 1
    k = k + 1

#delete types from drop list that aren't numeric
col_types['drop_it'] = drop_it
col_types = col_types.loc[col_types["drop_it"] == 1]

#finally drop columns that are in drop list
for col_to_drop in col_types.index.values.tolist():
    df = df.drop([col_to_drop], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.'

Try to delete the bin folder and rebuild it again. It works for me.

Comment: This answer is not related to the question. Could be another question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).