# Why can't I filter Pandas dataframe on numeric column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using Pandas to analyze data from csv. The dataframe look like this:

```
    tech_nbr    door_age    service_spend   service_calls
0   2   -7,987  1   3
1   3   -7,987  1   3
2   231561  -7,987  1   3
3   2531885 13  1   3
4   A451349 9   1   3
```

Now I want to filter out all the rows with negative `door_age` such as row 0 and 1 using the following command.

```
df_filtered = df.filter(df.door_age > 0)
```

However I got error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I guess there some values of ages are not numeric, so I added the following line to drop rows with non-numeric `door_age` based on [Remove non-numeric rows in one column with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961028/remove-non-numeric-rows-in-one-column-with-pandas/33975750)

```
df[df.door_age.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]
```

It did seem to remove a lot of rows, but I still got the same error. So I also filtered out rows with null values for `door_age` using `df = df.dropna(subset=['door_age']). However it did not help either.

Why am I still getting this error?

Comment: Can you *explicitly check* the `dtype` of your numeric column before before and after your attempt to remove non-numeric rows? you can use `df.dtypes` or `series.dtype` for this.

Comment: @jpp it is `object` before and after. Should I change the whole column type at the beginning then?

Comment: Yes, use `df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')`. Non-numeric values will become `np.nan`.

Comment: @jpp it works now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure your series is of numeric type *before* you attempt any numeric calculations.

In this case, you can coerce non-numeric values to `np.nan`:

```
df['door_age'] = pd.to_numeric(df['door_age'], errors='coerce')
```