# How to keep just the numbers on a column dataframe that also has strings?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have the following column in my dataframe:

```
Column1   Column2    Column3     Column4
a            1           2           a     
1            2           a           c
b            3           c           d
3            2           1           b
4            2           1           a
c            1           d           a
```

The type of these columns is `object`, I would like to convert `Column1`, `Column2` and `Column3` to numeric type `int8` while keeping `Column4` as type object. To do so, I had tried to use `pd.to_numeric(data.Column1)` (I was planning to do the same after with `Column2` and `Column3`) but I get the following error:

`ValueError: Unable to parse string "a" at position 0`

Which is obvious why it is happening. I was wondering if there is any way that would allow me to get rid of of that rows formed by strings in these 3 columns so after that, I would get:

```
Column1    Column 2    Column 3   Column 4
3            2           1           b
4            2           1           a
```

Is there a way to achieve so? Or is there another way that would allow me to?

**Edit:** I have checked the question in [Remove non-numeric rows in one column with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961028/remove-non-numeric-rows-in-one-column-with-pandas), but it didn't solve my problem, as I have more columns in my dataset than just two and one of them I don't want to convert it to numeric.

Comment: Use `df[pd.to_numeric(df.Column1, errors='coerce').notnull()]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) for replace non numeric to missing values, then remove `NaN`s rows by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and last cast to `integer`s:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).dropna().astype(int)
print (df)
   Column1  Column2  Column3
3        3        2        1
4        4        2        1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x,errors='coerce')))
   Column1  Column2  Column3
0      NaN      1.0      2.0
1      1.0      2.0      NaN
2      NaN      NaN      NaN
3      3.0      2.0      1.0
4      4.0      2.0      1.0
5      NaN      1.0      NaN
```

EDIT:

Another solution is check if not missing values with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
cols = ['Column1','Column2','Column3']
#define columns for check numeric
mask = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).notnull().all(axis=1)
#filtering
df = df[mask]
#converting to integers
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(int)
print (df)
   Column1  Column2  Column3 Column4
3        3        2        1       b
4        4        2        1       a

print (df.dtypes)
Column1     int32
Column2     int32
Column3     int32
Column4    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you! How could I approach it if one of my columns is formed of strings and I don't want to convert it to numeric? I have edited my question to ilustraste it. I guess I couldn't apply a lambda in that case, am I right?

Comment: @Marisa - Better is filtering columns for check with list, answer was edited.

Comment: Mask is returning me all the entries as False. I checked ``df.Column2[0]`` and it has returned me that is of type string ("1"). Could it be because as I have strings is taking everything as so?

Comment: @Marisa - Maybe need `mask = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.str.strip('"'), errors='coerce')).notnull().all(axis=1)` ?

Comment: Still is not working, the numbers are not between " " in my dataset. I just wrote them before to stressed the fact that they are strings.

Comment: @Marisa - Is possible check if some whitespaces or similar in data, e.g. by `print (df[cols].to_dict('l'))` ? Because it seems data related problem.

Comment: I get ``{'Column2': ['1', '2', '3', '2', '2', '1'], 'Column3': ['2', 'a', 'c', '1', '1', 'd'], 'Column1': ['a', '1', 'b', '3', '4', 'c']}``

Comment: @Marisa - I check both solutions by `df = pd.DataFrame({'Column2': ['1', '2', '3', '2', '2', '1'], 'Column3': ['2', 'a', 'c', '1', '1', 'd'], 'Column1': ['a', '1', 'b', '3', '4', 'c']})` and working nice.

Comment: @Marisa - Problem is with real data?

Comment: Yes, it is. Maybe I should ask to the person who sent it to send it in a different format

Comment: @Marisa - Yes, good idea. If working nice sample data problem is in data format obviously.