# Filter out non-numeric values from column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following column in pandas DataFrame:

```
col1
1.2
1.4
3.1
aa
bb
NaN
```

I need to calculate the minimum value in the column `col1` while ignoring all empty and non-numeric values.

If I do `df[col1].min()`, it only ignores empty values, but I still get this error:

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

Comment: This post looks like it might answer your question:[remove non-numeric rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961028/remove-non-numeric-rows-in-one-column-with-pandas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with [`pd.to_numeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
pd.to_numeric(df.col1,errors='coerce').min()
#1.2
#or df.col1.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x,errors='coerce')).min() <- slow
```

Answer (score 1):

I think of this as two steps:

1. Convert all elements in the column to numeric types. `NaN` is a numeric type, so it's safe to coerce all string values to `NaN`.
2. Call `min` on the resulting (cleaned) column.

To do step one, try testing each element to see if it is an instance of `numbers.Number`, [the base class for all Python numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/numbers.html).
If it is, return the element. If it isn't, return `NaN`.

```py
import numbers
import numpy as np

def coerce_to_numeric(value):
    if isinstance(value, numbers.Number):
        return value
    else:
        return np.NaN

# Returns a cleaned version of df[col1]
clean_col = df[col1].apply(coerce_to_numeric)
```

Then simply add the `.min()` to get the minimum value of the cleaned column.

```py
clean_col.min()
```