# Remove rows that are not a number or a date from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question similar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961028/remove-non-numeric-rows-in-one-column-with-pandas) except instead of only having numbers and text, my column has numbers, text and dates in them. How do I remove all rows that have values other than numbers and dates?

For example, I have a generic dataframe:

| id | Nums and Dates |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 1/1/2021 |
| 3 | AABBC |
| 4 | 20 |
| 5 | 1/2/2021 |

And after removal, it should look like this.

| id | Nums and Dates |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 1/1/2021 |
| 4 | 20 |
| 5 | 1/2/2021 |

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please remember to accept the best solution as answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. Thank you! Please see the following for more info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create two series that checks for dates and numbers with `to_datetime` and `to_numeric` and only keep non-null rows with `notnull()`. Passing `errors='coerce'` returns null to non-dates / non-numbers:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Nums and Dates'], errors='coerce')
nums = pd.to_numeric(df['Nums and Dates'], errors='coerce')
df[(dates.notnull()) | (nums.notnull())]

Out[1]:
   id  Nums and Dates
0   1              40
1   2        1/1/2021
3   4              20
4   5        1/2/2021
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the name of your dataframe as `df` and the name of your column as `Nums and Dates`, try this:

```
not_str_values = [value for value in df if type(value) is not str]
```

Then:

```
df = df.loc[df['Nums and Dates'].isin(not_str_values)]
```

Answer (score 1):

With contains and regex, You can do in one pass through the column. You can remove
the rows which has alphabets.

```
df[~df['Nums and Dates'].str.contains(r'[A-Za-z]', regex=True)]

id  Nums and Dates
0   1   40
1   2   1/1/2021
3   4   20
4   5   1/2/2021
```