# Remove pandas dataframe row if one column's element is non-numeric

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have been searching for an answer for this simple thing for an hour now. I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
   title      |   price

"some text 1"     124.5
"some text 2"     543.2
"some text 3"     156.2
"some text 4"     "Price N/A"
"some text 5"     216.7
```

I want to remove the rows that don't contain an actual float price. I tried the suggestion from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33975750/5016028):

```
raw_data[raw_data.price.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]
```

and I get:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'
```

Nothing seems to work for such a simple operation. I tried pretty much all the answers I found on stack and elsewhere.

Comment: The error might indicate that you are using Python 2. Are you using Python 3?

Comment: Python 3.8 is the only one I use.

Comment: What about  using isinstance(x, float) ?

Comment: raw_data[raw_data.price.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, float))]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the 'to_numeric' operation of pandas which will throw up an error when a string value is met. This error will be handled by 'coerce' which forces the content to null. We then use the 'notnull' operation to filter this particular row.

```
df[pd.to_numeric(df['price'], errors='coerce').notnull()]
```

Comment: Always try to add some comment to your code and remember to use four spaces before the text. It will be displayed in a proper format then.

Comment: @Arkadiusz Thank you. I have edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You get an error, since you are applying `(lambda x: x.isnumeric())` on a `float`.

`float.isnumeric()` doesn't exist, but you can use `isinstance(x, t)`, which returns `True` if x is of a type t.

```
raw_data[raw_data['price'].apply(lambda x : isinstance(x, float))]
```