# Data type issue in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I downloaded SF Salaries.csv data from Kaggle and stored it as sal.csv. I tried to find the average BasePay using:

```
sal['BasePay'].mean()
```

I recieved the following error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

After checking the data info, I found out that BasePay and some other columns that are supposed to be of type float are of type object. To change the type I use the following code:

```
cols = ['BasePay','OvertimePay','OtherPay','Benefits']
sal[cols] = sal[cols].astype(float)
```

But I receive the following error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Not Provided'

I tried to specify type on import using:

```
sal = pd.read_csv('Salaries.csv', dtype={0:int,1:str,2:str,3:float,4:float,5:float,6:float,7:float,8:float,9:int,10:float,11:str,12:float})
```

Again I recieved an error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'PT'

Comment: Your data columns include the strings "Not Provided" and "PT".  The are causing the conversion errors.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961028/remove-non-numeric-rows-in-one-column-with-pandas.